# Utilizing A-Frame with Squarespace to build a WebVR website

Tags: squarespace, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to make a WebVR website. I currently use Squarespace as my website builder (don't judge me). When I'm in the code injection section to include my code into the header I use the code below that's provided by A-Frame's website:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/{{ version }}/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

However, I don't see the standard Google Cardboard Icon at the lower right-hand corner. Am I doing something wrong, or does Squarespace not enable this functionality yet?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in the website, replace `version` with `0.3.2`

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
```